# Appending individual characters from string onto a char pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers, dynamic-allocation

I'm writing a parser in C, and I've got some code that looks like this:

```
char *consume_while(parser *self, int(*test)(char)) {
    char *result;
    while (eof(self) && (*test)(next_char(self))) {
         // append the return value from the function consumed_char(self)
         // onto the "result" string defined above.
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I'm kinda new to the whole string manipulation aspect of C, so how would I append the character returned from the function `consumed_char(self)` to the `result` char pointer? I've seen people using the `strcat` function, but that wont work as it takes two constant char pointers, but I'm dealing with a char* and a char. In java it would be something like this:

```
result += consumed_char(self);
```

What's the equivalent in C?
Thanks :)

Comment: It would be easier to read if you changed `(*test)(next_char(self))` to `test(next_char(self))`.

Comment: Cheers for the tip! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, strings do not exist as a type, they are just `char` arrays with a null-terminating character. This means, assuming your buffers are big enough and filled with zeroes, it can be as simple as:

```
result[(strlen(result)] = consumed_char(self);
```

if not, your best bet is to use `strcat` and change your `consumed_self` function to return a `char *`.

That being said, writing a parser without basic understanding of C-style strings, is, to say the least, quite ambitious.

Comment: Thanks, currently implementing something along these lines, but I've gotta go to college soon

Comment: The point here is **assuming your buffers are big enough**. It is a frequent cause of crash and (one of) the reason(s) for string in C++. But I do agree with your last sentence :-)

Comment: Well I do know that char* is a char array thats null terminated '\0'. I just wanted a solution that's dynamic and uses malloc, perhaps I wasn't clear.